# Zeros of Brownian motion

Tags: probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

I wanted to find out why for a Brownian motion $(B_t)_t$ almost surely for every $s\geq 0$ there exist $u,t\geq s$ s.t. 
$$B_u<0<B_t.$$
I know that BM has to have zeros on every intervall $[0, \epsilon].$ But as $B_s$ varies in $\omega$, I am confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $W_t$ is a Brownian motion, then $B_t = t W_{1/t}$ with $B_0 = 0$ is also a Brownian motion. The switching of signs of $W_t$ on the interval $[s, \infty)$ corresponds to the switching of signs of $B_t$ on the interval $(0, \tfrac{1}{s}]$.

Comment: True. Thanks a lot....

Comment: To wrap up I would also add: let $\tau_a$ be the time of hitting level $a$ by a Brownian motion $B$. Then we know that $\tau_a(\omega) < \infty$ a.s. (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1495143/prove-that-the-first-hitting-time-tau-x-inf-left-t-ge-0b-t-x-right-of-a or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749267/brownian-motion-hitting-time-is-finite-yet-has-infinite-expectation),  and hence to get those switchings of a sign we only need to wait till $\tau_1$ then till $\tau_{-1}$, and so on.